# Uploading to flickr using their upload api (PHP)

Tags: php, upload, flickr

I am trying to construct a custom upload script that uploads to a defined flickr account, I'm looking for something other than phpflickr (which uses the deprecated version of the flickr api). I know how to authorize flickr calls in the new method and have successfully used at least half-a-dozen of their methods but I'm failing to understand how to upload (mainly due to the fact of very limited documentation).

Here is my authorization call that I'm using:

```
<?php
$url  = "format=" . $this->format;
$url .= "&method=" . $method;
$url .= "&nojsoncallback=1";
$url .= "&oauth_consumer_key=" . $this->flickr_key;
$url .= "&oauth_nonce=" . $this->nonce;
$url .= "&oauth_signature_method=" . $this->sig_method;
$url .= "&oauth_timestamp=" . $this->timestamp;
$url .= "&oauth_token=" . $access_token;
$url .= "&oauth_version=1.0";
$url .= "&photoset_id=" . $photoset_id;

$baseurl            = "GET&" . urlencode( $flickr_upload_call ) . "&" . urlencode( $url );
$hashkey            = $this->flickr_secret . "&" . $access_token_secret;
$oauth_signature    = base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $baseurl, $hashkey, true ));

$url_parameters = array(
    'method'                =>$method,
    'oauth_consumer_key'    =>$this->flickr_key,
    'photoset_id'           =>$photoset_id,
    'format'                =>$this->format,
    'nojsoncallback'        =>'1',
    'oauth_nonce'           =>$this->nonce,
    'oauth_timestamp'       =>$this->timestamp,
    'oauth_signature_method'=>$this->sig_method,
    'oauth_version'         =>'1.0',
    'oauth_token'           =>$access_token,
    'oauth_signature'       =>$oauth_signature
);

/* Now that we have encoded the parameters for our ouath_signature
*  and have reformated them for the url we need to send... we must
*  re-urlencode them too. */

$parameters_string = "";
foreach ( $url_parameters as $key=>$value )
    $parameters_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&";

$url = $flickr_api_call . "?" . $parameters_string;
```

So, what I need to know is how to change this to allow for the flickr upload api to accept it; any ways I can do this better, or how can I use what is in phpflickr and convert it to the new method to suit my needs?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too, did you get it to work? Here is my try to upload pic to Flickr in PHP http://pastebin.com/z7MU1KQt, but I'm getting this error `err code="93" msg="POST size too large! Try something smaller, mmkay?` Maybe we can get a working example out of both?!

Comment: @Uli: No, I have yet to figure this out (as I'm sure you've noticed ... there's very limited valid [OAuth] data on the subject)! I've been pouring as much time and effort into this as I can ... here is my code: [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/yy8PBRWe) Here are some other links that might help us figure this out: [DPZFlickr](https://github.com/dopiaza/DPZFlickr) and [flickr uplaod example](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html) NOTE: not in curl and uses old method. Hope this helps ... if you figure it out let me know! ;) if you need anything else let me know!

Comment: Did you get this to work?